# actionListener under dynamic ui:include not working in p:dialog

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to implement a p:dialog. There is a select list in it. On the basis of selected item I need to update the templates on the dialog box. This is working fine. But if I have a `<p:commandButton>` in the dynamically rendered template, then its actionListener never gets fired.

Example: view.xhtml

```
<p:dialog modal="true" id="addSocialMediaAddressDialogPanel" widgetVar="addSocialMediaAddressDialog" width="500" >
<h:form id="addSocialMediaAddressForm">
    <h:messages />
    <p:selectOneMenu id="currentAddingSocialMedia" value="#{requestScope.selectedMedia}" >  
        <f:selectItems value="#{WebResource.getListByName('SOCIAL_MEDIAS')}" />
        <p:ajax update="addSocialMediaAddressContentPanel" process="@this" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <p:outputPanel id="addSocialMediaAddressContentPanel">
        <ui:include src="#{contactBean.resolveTemplate(requestScope.selectedMedia)}"/>
    </p:outputPanel>    
</h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

I have templates like this

```
templates
    |_ twitter.xhtml
    |_ facebook.xhtml
    |_ googlePlus.xhtml
```

twitter.xhtml

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h:outputLabel  styleClass="standardText" value="Twitter Screen Name"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p:inputText id="twitterScreenName" value="#{requestScope.twitterScreenName}"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p:commandButton value="Add Account" actionListener="#{contactBean.addTwitterAccount(requestScope.twitterScreenName)}" styleClass="btn-blue" process="@form" update=":growl, :messageForm"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And this is the backing bean

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class ContactBean implements Serializable {

    private static String SOCIAL_MEDIA_ACCOUNTS_TEMPLATE_PARENT_DIRECTORY = "/templates/";

    public void addTwitterAccount(String screenName){
        //this contiains the implmentation
    }

    public String resolveTemplate(String socialMedia){
        if(socialMedia.equalsIgnoreCase("Twitter")){
            return SOCIAL_MEDIA_ACCOUNTS_TEMPLATE_PARENT_DIRECTORY + "twitter.xhtml";
        }
        if(socialMedia.equalsIgnoreCase("Facebook")){
            return SOCIAL_MEDIA_ACCOUNTS_TEMPLATE_PARENT_DIRECTORY + "facebook.xhtml";
        }
        else if(socialMedia.equalsIgnoreCase("Google+")){
            return SOCIAL_MEDIA_ACCOUNTS_TEMPLATE_PARENT_DIRECTORY + "googlePlus.xhtml";
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

In this scenario I am unable to fire any actionListener which is the part of any of the  template under templates directory. I am using JSF 2.1.7 and Primefaces 3.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is here:

```
<ui:include src="#{contactBean.resolveTemplate(requestScope.selectedMedia)}"/>
```

This is not only evaluated during the initial HTTP request wherein the form is been displayed, but this is also evaluated during the subsequent HTTP request wherein the form submit is to be processed.

The `selectedMedia` seems to be a request scoped variable which get lost by end of initial request. So on the subsequent HTTP request of processing the form submit, it would evaluate as `null` and no template will be included at all during building the view. This way  JSF won't be able to run the `decode()` of the command button component and hence its action will never be determined and queued.

You need to make sure that the `selectedMedia` variable is retained on subsequent HTTP request. One of the ways is to pass it to the subsequent request as request parameter by `<f:param>` inside the command button or a `<input type="hidden">` inside the form.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC. This explains the issue. I have now changed the selectedMedia to be sessionScope and now it is working fine.

Comment: You're welcome. Putting it in the session scope would however affect the same page in multiple browser tabs/windows.

Answer (score 0):

Method for actionListener in bean should have `ActionEvent` parameter. See this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-actionlistener-example/)

Comment: I have tried this also but it is not working like this even. When I click the button form never gets submitted.

Comment: Did you try surrounding that button with `<h:form>`?

Comment: That's only the case if no argument is been specified. The OP has however overriden it to pass arguments (using the new EL 2.2 feature of invoking methods with specific arguments). Further, nesting forms is illegal in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove `<h:form>` used in the child template**. Keep only one `<h:form>` in the parent template and remove it in all other child templates which you have included in the parent template using `<ui:include>`